# Structuring python code to run a message through subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am in a process of building a simple remote shell tool to communicate with Windows 10. Server sends a "message" through its own shell to the client who runs the message. I need this received message to be run by other process other that default cmd (shell=True) - a specified app.exe.  Here is the code that runs on the client:
1)

```
def work( storage, message ) :
    import subprocess   
    process = subprocess.Popen([message], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)

    #Launch the shell command:
    output = process.communicate()

    print output[0]
```

I tried including "app.exe" or "cmd"  to execute the message but with that I get error: TypeError: bufsize must be an integer.

I have also tried pinpointing the issue locally and I can run:
2)

```
import subprocess
import sys
subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\app.exe", "-switch"] + sys.argv[1:], shell=False)
```

and pass arguments from a command terminal and it works as it should. Now I am trying to apply the same logic to a remote execution with my program and use either solution 1 or 2.

Update:
3) Trying to implement what I did locally to a remote solution:

```
def work( storage, message ) :
    import subprocess
    import sys

    process = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\app.exe", "-switch"] + sys.argv[1:], shell=False)

    #Launch the shell command:
    output = process.communicate()

    print output[0]
```

I tried replacing sys.argv[1:] with message but I get:
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: What exactly is `message`? I suspect all you need is `Popen(["...\\app.exe", "-switch", message], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None)`.

Comment: message is user input: dir, whoami, system commands etc.

Answer (score 0):

`shell=True` doesn't mean the first argument to `Popen` is a list of arguments to the shell; it just means the first argument is *processed* by the shell, rather than being arguments to whatever system call your system would use to execute a new process.

In this case, you appear to want to run `app.exe` with a given argument; that's simply

```
cmd = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\app.exe"
subprocess.Popen([cmd, "-switch", message], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

@chepner sir, you are a very helpful. That was it! I am so happy, thanks for your help.

Your solution:

```
Popen(["...\\app.exe", "-switch", message], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None)
```

That was the badger!